# trino or presto cast '["b", "a", "b", "c"]' into a values array

Tags: sql, presto, trino

is there a good way to cast a json type of array `'["b", "a", "b", "c"]'` into an array.

e.g. something that looks like this

```
select array['b', 'a', 'c', 'b'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it in the [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html):

```sql
select CAST(JSON '["b", "a", "b", "c"]' AS ARRAY(varchar));
```

Comment: If answer works for you - mark it as accepted (checkmark to the left), even if it is your own one.